# Error: Signal parameter requires signal expression on function call

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

Short question:

I've written a function that takes a signal integer as parameter. The compiler throws the error `signal parameter requires signal expression` when I call `my_function(INTEGER_SIGNAL - 5)` in a process.
Could someone explain to me what a signal expression is and how I can call this function correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't help when a vendor doesn't use language found in the standard. IEEE Std 1076-2008 4.2.2.1 Formal parameter lists "In a subprogram call, the actual designator (see 6.5.7.1) associated with a formal parameter of class signal shall be a name denoting a signal. The actual designator associated with a formal of class variable shall be a name denoting a variable. The actual designator associated with a formal of class constant shall be an expression." A name can be a primary in an expression (which can standalone, 9.1), but the actual in the parameter list can't be an expression.

Comment: The default class of a formal parameter (in a function declaration) is constant. The only advantage of using a signal parameter would be having access to predefined attributes of a signal (which would require a prefix that's a signal designator, hence the restriction).

Answer (score 3):

Generally for functions you want to instead use a constant class parameter.

Signal class parameters require that you connect them to a signal - ie: no expressions.   You only need a signal inside of a function when you use a signal parameter, such as 'event.   For a procedure, you also need a signal when you expect the object to update - such as when it is used in a wait statement or is read after a wait statement (and you expect a potentially updated value).

With a constant class parameters allow you to connect them with any value of that type.   That value can come from an expression or a literal value (X"4A").   A signal name or a variable name are simple forms of expressions.

Constant class also happens to be the default for inputs of you do not specify the class of the parameter.   In the following code, parameters A and B are both constant class parameters.

```
function fred (
   constant A : integer ; 
            B : integer
) return integer is 
 ...
end function fred ;
```